Only latest notification for my flutter app is displayed when phone comes from offline to online
Only one notification (The latest) is received and displayed in my flutter app when phone goes from offline to online despite multiple notifications being sent to device. What might be the issue.
I have setup a firebase background message handler where I only print the incoming notification and a foreground handler as well to handle foreground notification as shown below.
Future<void> initiateForegroundNotifications(BuildContext context) async {
 void handleNotificationTapRoute(String payload) {
  final payloadMap = jsonDecode(payload) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  final notificationtitle = payloadMap['title'].toString().toLowerCase();
  final notificationBody = payloadMap['body'].toString().toLowerCase();
  final notificationData = payloadMap['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;

  if (notificationtitle.contains('new order')) {
    if (notificationBody.contains('await order')) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        AppRouter.myCartPageRoute,
        arguments: true,
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        AppRouter.sellerOrderChildrenRoute,
        arguments: {
          'name': 'New',
          'orderCount': 0,
          'isNotificationRoute': true,
        },
      );
    }
  }
  if (notificationtitle.contains('declined') ||
      notificationtitle.contains('paid successfully')) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      AppRouter.shopHistoryPageRoute,
      arguments: true,
    );
  }
  if (notificationtitle.contains('approved')) {
    final titleParts = notificationtitle.split(' ');
    final orderId = titleParts[1];

    final orderModel = HiveServiceImpl()
        .retrieveCartData()!
        .cartDetails
        .firstWhere(
          (element) => element.orderModel!.orderNumber == orderId,
        )
        .orderModel;

    final productModel = HiveServiceImpl()
        .retrieveCartData()!
        .cartDetails
        .firstWhere(
          (element) => element.orderModel!.orderNumber == orderId,
        )
        .product;

    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      AppRouter.myOrderPageRoute,
      arguments: {
        'orderModel': orderModel,
        'orderId': orderId,
        'productModel': productModel,
        'isNotificationRoute': true,
      },
    );
  }

  if (notificationtitle.contains('chat')) {
    final regExp = RegExp(r'\bfrom\b (.+)');
    final sendername = regExp.firstMatch(notificationtitle);
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      AppRouter.chatMessagingRoute,
      arguments: ChatMessagingRouteData(
        sendername!.group(1)!,
        notificationData['SenderId'] as String,
        notificationData['SessionId'] as String,
        notificationData['Shopownerid'] as String,
        notificationData['shopId'] as String,
      ),
    );
  }

  if (notificationtitle.contains('fulfilled')) {
    if (notificationBody.contains('congratulations')) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        AppRouter.walletAccountPageRoute,
        arguments: true,
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        AppRouter.shopHistoryPageRoute,
        arguments: true,
      );
    }
  }

  if (notificationtitle.contains('received') ||
      notificationtitle.contains('multiple orders')) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      AppRouter.sellerOrderChildrenRoute,
      arguments: {
        'name': 'InTransit',
        'orderCount': 0,
        'isNotificationRoute': true,
      },
    );
  }

  if (notificationtitle.contains('disputed')) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      AppRouter.sellerOrderChildrenRoute,
      arguments: {
        'name': 'Disputed',
        'orderCount': 0,
        'isNotificationRoute': true,
      },
    );
  }
}

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
}
final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> onForegroundTapNotification(
  NotificationResponse notificationResponse,
) async {
  handleNotificationTapRoute(notificationResponse.payload!);
}

const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
const iOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  settings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onForegroundTapNotification,
);

const channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'High Importance Notifications',
  description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
  importance: Importance.max,
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  final notification = message.notification;

  final longdata = notification?.body ?? '';
  final bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(longdata);

  final androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    channel.id,
    channel.name,
    channelDescription: channel.description,
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
  );

  const iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = DarwinNotificationDetails();
  final platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
  );

  if (notification != null) {
    final payloadMap = <String, dynamic>{
      'title': notification.title,
      'body': notification.body,
      'data': message.data,
    };

    final jsonString = jsonEncode(payloadMap);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: jsonString,
    );
  }
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  final payloadMap = <String, dynamic>{
    'title': message.notification!.title,
    'body': message.notification!.body,
    'data': message.data,
  };

  final jsonString = jsonEncode(payloadMap);
  handleNotificationTapRoute(jsonString);
});

}
